# Is it possible to determine capacity and voltage rating of an unknown electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: voltage, measurement, capacitance, electrolytic-capacitor, maximum-ratings

Today I found a big electrolytic capacitor in a scrap yard. It is about 9 cm in diameter and 16 cm high. The only thing that is marked on it is polarity but nothing else. How can I measure its capacitance when I even don't know its maximum voltage rating?

Comment: You don't even know it is not broken. Leave it on the scrapyard.

Comment: Use a variable power supply and slowly increase the voltage.  When it explodes, you went past the rated voltage. ;-)

Comment: @TimH After it explodes, back off the voltage a bit.

Comment: If you can get a credible capacitance measurement then you can ballpark the volt rating bacause you know the size and can estimate its vintage .Run it up at very low current waiting for the current to fall .Gradualy increase the voltage .Rate your cap at a voltage where current goes to basicly zero .

Answer (score 1):

To safely discharge a capacitor: After power is removed, connect a 20,000 Ω, 5-watt resistor across the capacitor terminals for five seconds. Use your multimeter to confirm the capacitor is fully discharged.

1. Use your digital multimeter (DMM) to ensure all power to the circuit
   is OFF. If the capacitor is used in an ac circuit, set the
   multimeter to measure ac voltage. If is used in a dc circuit, set
   the DMM to measure dc voltage.
2. Visually inspect the capacitor. If leaks, cracks, bulges or other
   signs of deterioration are evident, replace the capacitor.
3. Turn the dial to the Capacitance Measurement mode ( Capacitance
   symbol ). The symbol often shares a spot on the dial with another
   function. In addition to the dial adjustment, a function button
   usually needs to be pressed to activate a measurement. Consult your
   multimeter’s user manual for instructions.
4. For a correct measurement, the capacitor will need to be removed
   from the circuit. Discharge the capacitor as described in the
   warning above.

**Note**: Some multimeters offer a Relative (REL) mode. When measuring low capacitance values, the Relative mode can be used to remove the capacitance of the test leads. To place a multimeter in Relative mode for capacitance, leave the test leads open and press the REL button. This removes the residual capacitance value of the test leads.

5. Connect the test leads to the capacitor terminals. Keep test leads
   connected for a few seconds to allow the multimeter to automatically
   select the proper range.
6. Read the measurement displayed. If the capacitance value is within
   the measurement range, the multimeter will display the capacitor’s
   value. It will display OL if a) the capacitance value is higher than
   the measurement range or b) the capacitor is faulty.

[From this site.](http://en-us.fluke.com/training/training-library/test-tools/digital-multimeters/how-to-measure-capacitance-with-a-digital-multimeter.html)